# Problems with Div and CSS

Tags: css, html

So, trying to figure out how to structure webpages, was trying to make a `bodyWrapper` to cover entire page using `max-height: 100%`, `max-width: 100%`. Then I was going to attempt to put all my other elements using `20%` etc... I was hoping it will help when resizing, is that the proper way? Anyways, my CODING problem is my `div` is only covering one line of the entire page.

My code;

```css
html {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%
}

body {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#bodyWrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="myCssTemplate.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bodyWrapper">
    <p> This is a test.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: First, you should look at `bootstrap`, it will help you structuring your page and your content. Secondly, the "problem" with your `div` is an expected behavior since you've set the maximum width ans height and the `width` and `height`.

Comment: I don't understand. What your trying to say, I'll look into bootstrap, but no idea what you mean by the div..

Comment: Don't use spaces for attribute values: `id="bodyWrapper"` instead of `id = "bodyWrapper"`, etcetera. also the `<meta>` name should be "viewport". Not "viewpoint".

Comment: Highly suggest looking into the built in [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) as a native alternative to bootstrap. It is definitely different, but it is a bit more straight forward, and less verbose in my opinion.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Bootstrap would not make solving this problem any easier.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the bodyWrapper `min-height` to 100vh. That mean it will take 100% viewport height.

```
#bodyWrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is often referred to as "Grid System". The most popular framework for grids is [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/). What Bootstrap does is changing the max-width property on so called media queries (e.g. 100%). Based on that you can create rows and columns. Columns have a relative width to their parent (row and containers), e.g. (like in your example) 20%.

Since this task has been done by multiple frameworks its quite important to understand **how** it works, but its not important to **implement** it by yourself. Just use a framework for this task.

Answer (score 0):

When using `max-height` or `max-width` you are asking the maximum height of the element to not be over the amount you wrote for (in your case 100%) so technically, impossible to cover all the page. So in  your case you'll have to ask for a minimum dimension.

```
#bodyWrapper
{
    height: 100%; /* Can also use min-height: 100%; */
    width: 100%; /* Can also use min-width: 100%; */
    background-color: black;
}
```

After that you'll be free to put other element inside your wrapper the width you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to set the `height:100%` to the root element of the DOM `html`....

`max-height:100%` will not work because `max-height` defines what can be the maximum height of the element if the inner content will be added like below snippet...it will help you to understand `max-height` concept.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lacinia, ipsum a posuere consequat, purus erat faucibus orci, vel porta leo odio vitae ligula. Maecenas interdum quis dui eu faucibus.</div>
```

back to the question you will need to set `min-height:100%` to the `#bodyWrapper` instead of `max-height` and also you don't have to set `max-width:100%` or `width:100%` to the `html`, `body`, `div`, because there are `block` element by default and `block` element always take `width:100%` if not specified and `width` value

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#bodyWrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="myCssTemplate.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bodyWrapper">
    <p> This is a test.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```